# MySQL, transfer values from one table to another depending of the weekday

Tags: mysql, events

I have one table where every worker chose the meal that he wants for each day of the week (kitchen_wishes), and contains an ID column, and columns Monday, Tuesday, etc. The selection is stored as an integer value.

and another table where the selection for THAT day is copied from the first table (food_for_today). This table contains one ID column (in same order as the first table) and another column - what_to_eat. It is pretty straight forward.

I try to create a daily event in the SQL database which would move the values for that day from the first table to the second, every day at 9:00, but I have various issues, generally with copying values from one table to another depending on the day.

Here is my code:

````
```

CREATE EVENT update_kitchen_wishes
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2020-09-02 09:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
  DO

     SET @today = WEEKDAY(CURDATE()+1);
     
     INSERT INTO food_for_today (what_to_eat)
     SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN @today = 1 THEN Monday
        WHEN @today = 2 THEN Tuesday
        WHEN @today = 3 THEN Wednesday
        WHEN @today = 4 THEN Thursday
        WHEN @today = 5 THEN Friday
        WHEN @today = 6 THEN Saturday
        WHEN @today = 7 THEN Sunday
    END
    FROM kitchen_wishes;
````

Comment: Please be more specific about the problems you face, rather than just "I have various issues".

Comment: you are right sorry. when the code is like this, i get:
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'food_for_today.PRIMARY'

at the end i add 

WHERE worker_id = id;

and i get: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
even though this collumn exists in the food_for_today table.
whenever i change something i get another error, i cannot seem to get this right.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63694918/edit) to provide sample data, desired results, and the error that you are currently getting.

Comment: What is the point of doing this instead of directly query the main table? Your food_for_today  table looks like waste of resources and time. You should have a date in the kitchen_wishes table and that is all, you query it to retrieve data for the current day. Show us your table structure and sample of data